# Exclude specific items from list when sending POST form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, post

I have a
`List<TelephoneVm>`
in my ViewModel. View dynamically creates POST form with table rows based on items in that list.
I don't want to send all items that are in list back to controller. Only the ones with specific property set to `true`. How can I achieve this?

View:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Test">
...
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Objects.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">@i</th>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Objects[i].Number)</td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Objects[i].Id)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Objects[i].Number)
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Objects[i].Show)</td>
                </tr>
            }
...
</form>
```

When submitting form, entire list is sent, and I want to send list with items where `Show` property is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#YourForm').submit(function() {
   $("table tr input:checkbox:not(:checked)").closest("tr").remove()
});
```

Change "table" for a selector (id, class...) that select your table. When you submit your form, get all input not checked, select their row and remove the row. In this form, you don't send unchecked rows.

Update your form submit button to invoke the javascript code:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()"/>
```

And define a JavaScript function:

```
function submitForm() {
   $('#YourForm').submit(function() {
      $("table tr input:checkbox:not(:checked)").closest("tr").remove()
   });
}
```